# Saving a field from firestore that is an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a mobile app on React and I am having trouble understanding how to save a field from fire store that is an array.

Since I can't post images my database structure is all strings such as username, first name, etc but I have a field called follow list that is an array.

What I want to do is save the usernames from the following list into an array to later search fire store for the username's in the array, this is basically what I want to do so I can render my app's social Feed. I do know that I can probably create another subcollection and write something familiar to what I did to search for users but that was a QuerySnapShot which was overall documents not a specific one and I also know firebase creates an ID for arrays and it increases as the array gets bigger.

I do not want to end up making two more subcollections one for followers and following which I think not ideal right? My current approach is this

```html
export const fetchUserFollowing = async (username) => {
     const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(username)
     let results = []

     ref
        .get()
        .then( doc => {
            let data = doc.data()
            results = data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return 'an error has occurred  ', err
        })
}
```

From what I understand is that a DocumentSnapShot .get() function returns an object but what I want is to store follow list into results and then return that but I am not sure how to manipulate the object return to just give me follow List which is an array

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/firestore/reference/DocumentSnapshot
link to docs

Comment: "Since I can't post images my database structure is ..." You can post the actual JSON as text, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking of us. What does the code you shared do? And what do you expect it to do differently?

Comment: right now my code is getting data from the database but i want it to only save the following list field which is an array

Comment: Are you trying to get a single field from the document? In that case you can just sub-address it from `doc.data()`. Something like `let data = doc.data(); results = data.field_you_want`.

Comment: Or is your problem that the function that calls `fetchUserFollowing` doesn't get the results. That would be explained by the fact that you're not returning anything. You'll want to have a look at promises to learn how to return a value from an async function.

Comment: I am trying to get a single field but its array does that method work for arrays? i have only used it to save strings and no there are results but its an object as it says in the docs I just want a specific field that is an array

Comment: Accessing an array is no different than accessing another field. If it doesn't work, show what you've tried and tell what didn't work about it. What did each line do? And what did you expect it to do?

Comment: I did not know that arrays can be accessed the same way, so                                      like you suggested `let data = doc.data(); results = data.field_you_want. –` would allow me to get an array so i can do `let data = doc.data() results = data.followList`